# Invalid query php without error message

Tags: php, mysql

This is my query:

```
$query =  "INSERT INTO studente (Nome, Cognome, Matricola, Username, Codice)  
     SELECT 'Nome', 'Cognome', 'Matricola', 'Username' FROM studenti_in_sessione
     WHERE studenti_in_sessione.Username = '".$_REQUEST['username']. "';" ; 
          $result = $db_handle->insertQuery($query);
```

This is insertQuery method:

```
function insertQuery($query) {
        $result = mysqli_query($this->conn,$query);
        if (!$result) {
            die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
        } else {
            return $result;
        }
    }
```

The method returns Invalid query: without error messages.

Possible that I wrote the query with "" or "" or actually is wrong, but I do not know where ...

Comment: remove single quotes around column names

Comment: learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: Think better dupplicate is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql

Comment: I remove single quotes but the method returns Invalid query: without error messages.